# Can javascript sort like windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, sorting, web

I need a way in Javascript to sort strings as in Windows but it seems it's impossible.

Windows explorer sorts like this:

```
1.jpg - 2.jpg - 3.jpg - ....
```

While Javascript sorts like this:

```
1.jpg - 10.jpg - 11.jpg - 2.jpg -...
```

Windows sorts based on the numeral value in the filename while Javascript just sorts by a characters' ASCII code.

Sometimes filenames aren't just numbers or text but a combination of both, e.G.:

```
"mark 01 in school.jpg"
"mark 02 in school.jpg"
"john 05 in theater.jpg"
```

What I need is a Javascript function that sorts like shown above.

My question is: is there a function in JS or how can I implement one on my own?

Comment: Of course it can, worse case you can write your own algorithm... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort

Comment: If it's combination of both, what is your expected result?

Comment: Corrected many english errors

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following algorithm for your sorting. 
It sorts based on characters.

http://www.davekoelle.com/files/alphanum.js

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write your own sort function and pass it as argument to sort method. Simple example:

```
your_array.sort(sortfunction)

function sortfunction(a, b){
     var num1 = extractNumberFrom(a);
     var num2 = extractNumberFrom(b);
     return num1 - num2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a sort callback that sorts on strings first, then checks for numbers and sorts those correctly as well, something like

```js
var arr = [
    "test2.jpg",
    "test10.jpg",
    "test1.jpg",
    "test11.jpg"
]

arr.sort(function(a,b) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        var _a = a.charAt(i), 
            _b = b.charAt(i),
            _c = _a.localeCompare(_b);
        
        if ( _c != 0 ) return isNaN(_a) || isNaN(_b) ? a.localeCompare(b) : _a - _b;
    }
    
});

document.body.innerHTML = '<pre>' + JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4) + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a `flexibleSort` function that first checks whether all your filename in an array has number only or not. If it has number only then it will compare it as Integer/number, otherwise it will treat it as String.

```js
var arr_number = ["2.jpg", "1.jpg", "3.jpg"];
var arr_string = ["mark 01 in school.jpg","mark 02 in school.jpg","john 05 in theater.jpg"];
var arr_number_1 = ["1.jpg","10.jpg","11.jpg","2.jpg"];
flexibleSort(arr_number);
flexibleSort(arr_string);
flexibleSort(arr_number_1);

function flexibleSort(obj){
 var all_number = true;
 $.each(obj, function(index, value){
     if(!$.isNumeric(value.split(".")[0])){
      all_number = false;
     }
 });
 if(all_number === true){
  obj.sort(function(a, b){return parseInt(a.split(".")[0])-parseInt(b.split(".")[0])});
 }else{
  obj.sort(function(a, b){return a > b});
 }
    $.each(obj, function(index, value){
     $('#result').append("<p>"+value+"</p>");
 });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```